# Not able to Start Elastic Search in Windows

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch

On running elasticsearch.bat in cmd :

> warning: ignoring JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\JAVA_HOME\openjdk-17.0.1;
> using bundled JDK [2022-07-11T10:50:46,384][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
> ] [MUTHU] version[8.3.0], pid[6080],
> build[zip/5b8b981647acdf1ba1d88751646b49d1b461b4cc/2022-06-23T22:48:49.607492124Z],
> OS[Windows 11/10.0/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit
> Server VM/18.0.1.1/18.0.1.1+2-6] [2022-07-11T10:50:46,391][INFO
> ][o.e.n.Node               ] [MUTHU] JVM home
> [C:\Users\muthu\Downloads\elasticsearch-8.3.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-8.3.0\jdk],
> using bundled JDK [true] [2022-07-11T10:50:46,392][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
> ] [MUTHU] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60,
> -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\muthu\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m,
> -Xms8138m, -Xmx8138m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4267704320, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.distribution.type=zip, --module-path=C:\Users\muthu\Downloads\elasticsearch-8.3.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-8.3.0\lib,
> -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server] [2022-07-11T10:50:49,211][INFO ][c.a.c.i.j.JacksonVersion ] [MUTHU]
> Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.13.2, jackson-core=2.13.2,
> jackson-databind=2.13.2.2, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.13.2,
> jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.13.2, azure-core=1.27.0, Troubleshooting
> version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,545][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,545][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [analysis-common]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,546][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [constant-keyword] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,546][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [data-streams]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,546][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [frozen-indices] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,547][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [ingest-common]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,547][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [ingest-geoip] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,547][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,548][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [kibana] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,548][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [lang-expression]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,549][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [lang-mustache] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,549][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [lang-painless]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,550][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [legacy-geo] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,550][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [mapper-extras]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,550][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [mapper-version] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,551][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [old-lucene-versions] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,551][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [parent-join]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,552][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [percolator] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,552][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [rank-eval]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,553][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [reindex] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,553][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [repositories-metering-api] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,553][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [repository-azure]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,554][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [repository-encrypted] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,554][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [repository-gcs]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,555][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [repository-s3] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,555][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [repository-url]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,556][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [runtime-fields-common] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,556][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [search-business-rules] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,557][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [searchable-snapshots] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,557][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [snapshot-based-recoveries] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,558][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [snapshot-repo-test-kit] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,558][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [spatial]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,559][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [transform] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,559][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [transport-netty4]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,560][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [unsigned-long] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,560][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [vector-tile]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [vectors] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,561][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [wildcard]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,562][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-aggregate-metric] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,562][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-analytics]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,563][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-async] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,563][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [x-pack-async-search] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,563][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [x-pack-autoscaling] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,564][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,564][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-core] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,565][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [x-pack-deprecation] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,565][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-enrich]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,566][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-eql] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,566][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-fleet]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,566][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-graph] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,567][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [x-pack-identity-provider] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,567][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,567][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-logstash] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,568][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,568][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-monitoring] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,569][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-ql]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,569][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-rollup] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,570][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-security]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,570][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-shutdown] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,570][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,571][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU]
> loaded module [x-pack-stack] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,571][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [x-pack-text-structure] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,572][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module
> [x-pack-voting-only-node] [2022-07-11T10:50:51,572][INFO
> ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:51,573][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [MUTHU] no
> plugins loaded [2022-07-11T10:50:55,410][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment
> ] [MUTHU] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Windows (C:)]], net
> usable_space [6.6gb], net total_space [117.9gb], types [NTFS]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:55,411][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [MUTHU]
> heap size [7.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
> [2022-07-11T10:50:55,525][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [MUTHU]
> node name [MUTHU], node ID [blR5jASzR-GtHp8cCsqjNA], cluster name
> [elasticsearch], roles [ml, data_hot, transform, data_content,
> data_warm, master, remote_cluster_client, data, data_cold, ingest,
> data_frozen] [2022-07-11T10:50:59,905][INFO ][o.e.x.s.Security
> ] [MUTHU] Security is enabled [2022-07-11T10:51:00,479][INFO
> ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [MUTHU] parsed [0] roles from file
> [C:\Users\muthu\Downloads\elasticsearch-8.3.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-8.3.0\config\roles.yml]
>
> [2022-07-11T10:51:01,649][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler]
> [MUTHU] [controller/5312] [Main.cc@123] controller (64 bit): Version
> 8.3.0 (Build 2ddb5323b2ad5a) Copyright (c) 2022 Elasticsearch BV [2022-07-11T10:51:02,533][INFO ][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator   ] [MUTHU]
> creating NettyAllocator with the following configs:
> [name=elasticsearch_configured, chunk_size=1mb,
> suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb,
> factors={es.unsafe.use_netty_default_chunk_and_page_size=false,
> g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb}]
> [2022-07-11T10:51:02,578][INFO ][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings ] [MUTHU]
> using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
> [2022-07-11T10:51:02,635][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [MUTHU]
> using discovery type [multi-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
> [2022-07-11T10:51:04,703][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [MUTHU]
> initialized [2022-07-11T10:51:04,704][INFO ][o.e.n.Node
> ] [MUTHU] starting ... [2022-07-11T10:51:04,722][INFO
> ][o.e.x.s.c.f.PersistentCache] [MUTHU] persistent cache index loaded
> [2022-07-11T10:51:04,723][INFO
> ][o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent] [MUTHU] deprecation
> component started [2022-07-11T10:51:05,004][INFO
> ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [MUTHU] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300},
> bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
> [2022-07-11T10:51:05,617][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService]
> [MUTHU] this node is locked into cluster UUID [vICcQF0LRnGmaEJTavBbaQ]
> but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [MUTHU]; remove this
> setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster
> bootstrap attempts [2022-07-11T10:51:05,802][INFO
> ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [MUTHU] elected-as-master ([1] nodes
> joined)[*FINISH_ELECTION*,
> {MUTHU}{blR5jASzR-GtHp8cCsqjNA}{lHHp8n91TFCQtiZV56u4ZA}{MUTHU}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}
> completing election], term: 5, version: 40, delta: master node changed
> {previous [], current
> [{MUTHU}{blR5jASzR-GtHp8cCsqjNA}{lHHp8n91TFCQtiZV56u4ZA}{MUTHU}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]}
> [2022-07-11T10:51:05,922][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService]
> [MUTHU] master node changed {previous [], current
> [{MUTHU}{blR5jASzR-GtHp8cCsqjNA}{lHHp8n91TFCQtiZV56u4ZA}{MUTHU}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]},
> term: 5, version: 40, reason: Publication{term=5, version=40}
> [2022-07-11T10:51:05,983][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor]
> [MUTHU] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on
> [blR5jASzR-GtHp8cCsqjNA][MUTHU][C:\Users\muthu\Downloads\elasticsearch-8.3.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-8.3.0\data]
> free: 6.6gb[5.6%], shards will be relocated away from this node;
> currently relocating away shards totalling [0] bytes; the node is
> expected to continue to exceed the high disk watermark when these
> relocations are complete [2022-07-11T10:51:06,038][INFO
> ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [MUTHU] publish_address
> {192.168.1.6:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
> [2022-07-11T10:51:06,041][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [MUTHU]
> started
> {MUTHU}{blR5jASzR-GtHp8cCsqjNA}{lHHp8n91TFCQtiZV56u4ZA}{MUTHU}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{ml.max_jvm_size=8535408640,
> ml.machine_memory=17066790912, xpack.installed=true}
> [2022-07-11T10:51:06,089][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [MUTHU]
> license [4b383951-c19c-4efc-8fb2-201b91e32e8c] mode [basic] - valid
> [2022-07-11T10:51:06,092][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.Realms         ] [MUTHU]
> license mode is [basic], currently licensed security realms are
> [reserved/reserved,file/default_file,native/default_native]
> [2022-07-11T10:51:06,098][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [MUTHU]
> recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
> [2022-07-11T10:51:06,257][ERROR][o.e.i.g.GeoIpDownloader  ] [MUTHU]
> exception during geoip databases update
> org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of
> [.geoip_databases] index are active
> at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.updateDatabases(GeoIpDownloader.java:134)
> ~[ingest-geoip-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
> at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloader.runDownloader(GeoIpDownloader.java:274)
> [ingest-geoip-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
> at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:102)
> [ingest-geoip-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
> at org.elasticsearch.ingest.geoip.GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.nodeOperation(GeoIpDownloaderTaskExecutor.java:48)
> [ingest-geoip-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
> at org.elasticsearch.persistent.NodePersistentTasksExecutor$1.doRun(NodePersistentTasksExecutor.java:42)
> [elasticsearch-8.3.0.jar:?]
> at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:768)
> [elasticsearch-8.3.0.jar:?]
> at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)
> [elasticsearch-8.3.0.jar:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> [?:?]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> [?:?]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?] [2022-07-11T10:51:06,266][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [MUTHU]
> current.health="RED" message="Cluster health status changed from
> [YELLOW] to [RED] (reason: [state recovered])."
> previous.health="YELLOW" reason="state recovered"

Comment: can you share your elasticsearch.yml content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error messages,

> high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [blR5jASzR-GtHp8cCsqjNA][MUTHU][

and

> [MUTHU] exception during geoip databases update
> org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: not all primary shards of
> [.geoip_databases] index are active at

It seems you don't have enough space allocated to your data folder of Elasticsearch, where Elasticsearch will store the index data. Try freeing up space in your Elasticsearch data folder, which you can find in the `elasticsearch.yml`. It's defined under `path.data` setting.